# What is the definition of $f \in C^{\infty}(\overline{U})$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am reading Evans' Partial Differential Equations, Chapter $5$. I am concerned about the notation $f \in C^{\infty}(\overline{U})$, for an open set $U$. Does it mean $f$ is $C^{\infty}(U)$ and that $f $ is **continuous** in $\overline{U}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For various reasons, derivatives are badly behaved on the boundary of regions. Accordingly we usually only define them on open sets, especially in dimension greater than $1$. Yet in PDEs we have to interact with boundaries, so we should assume something about behavior at the boundary as well. The usual way out is to assume that all your derivatives exist and are continuous on the *interior* and that the function is also continuous on the whole *closure* (including the boundary). It is more or less the same to assume that your function is actually only defined on $U$ but that it admits a continuous extension to $\overline{U}$. The meaning of this continuity is the same as it is for any mapping between metric spaces.

Comment: That's what I thought. So only $f$ needs to be continuous on the closure, with derivatives only defined on the open set $\Omega$.

Comment: One more question: If we have a function $u \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and we restrict it to an open domain $\Omega$, does $u \in C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$?

Comment: Sure, it's the composition of your original function with the inclusion map.

Answer (score 0):

It means that also the derivatives $f^{(k)}$, defined of $\Omega$, should be uniformly continuous on $\Omega$ so that they can be continuously and uniquely extended to $\overline{\Omega}$.